# mcsema using error,has someone use mcsema successful

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, llvm, reverse-engineering, elf

I flow the Official website to build mcsema using native build approach.Everything seems OK.Since my ida is on Windows,so I use the command of

```
%IDA_ROOT%\ida64.exe -S"C:\Users\dkl\Desktop\source\mcsema\tools\mcsema_disass\ida7\get_cfg.py --output
```

C:\Users\dkl\Desktop\output.cfg --arch amd64 --os linux" C:\Users\dkl\Desktop\work\t2\a.out

to generate output.cfg ,that is OK
then

```
mcsema-lift-11.0 --arch amd64 --os linux --cfg ./output.cfg --output ./output.bc
```

that is OK,then

```
remill-clang-11 -o ./output ./output.bc -lpthread -lm -ldl -llzma -Wl,--section-start=.section_1ff00000=0x1ff00000
```

COUNTER A ERROR

root@DESKTOP-CS6BMJI:/mnt/c/Users/dkl/Desktop# mcsema-lift-11.0 --arch amd64 --os linux --cfg ./output.cfg --output ./output.bc
root@DESKTOP-CS6BMJI:/mnt/c/Users/dkl/Desktop# remill-clang-11 -o ./output ./output.bc -lpthread -lm -ldl -llzma -Wl,--section-start=.section_1ff00000=0x1ff00000
warning: overriding the module target triple with x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [-Woverride-module]
1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/output-3e1099.o: in function sub_401020': llvm-link:(.text+0x152): undefined reference to __remill_jump'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/output-3e1099.o: in function sub_401040__start': llvm-link:(.text+0x2cb): undefined reference to __remill_function_call'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/output-3e1099.o: in function sub_401160___libc_csu_init': llvm-link:(.text+0x939): undefined reference to __remill_function_call'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/output-3e1099.o: in function sub_401000__init_proc': llvm-link:(.text+0xe2d): undefined reference to __remill_function_call'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/output-3e1099.o: in function ext_404040_printf': llvm-link:(.text+0x10da): undefined reference to __remill_function_call'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/output-3e1099.o:(.rodata+0x2138): undefined reference to `__mcsema_attach_call'
remill-clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
root@DESKTOP-CS6BMJI:/mnt/c/Users/dkl/Desktop#